# How to use Quickblox chat rooms for 1:1 chat?

Tags: quickblox

A chat room with only 2 users can be used for a 1:1 chat experience, but there are a few things that I could not clarify in Quickblox support info:

- how to get a list of the 1:1 rooms where I am involved? If I create rooms with myUserID_opponentUserID@muc.chat.quickblox.com, how can I get a list of rooms where my User ID is in the name of the room? All I could find was a [[QBChat instance] requestAllRooms]; but this gets a list of all rooms. Then I would have to parse the names in the app. Is there a way to add a filter to this request?
- how do I get the 1:1 chat rooms ordered by recently exchanged messages? I would like to get all the rooms where I am involved and order them from the most recent conversation to the most old conversation.

Maybe Custom Objects could come to the rescue?

- register the name of the rooms I am involved in when they are created
  register the time I join my rooms

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that:

1) you should perform

```
[[QBChat instance] requestAllRooms]
```

and in chat delegate method

```
chatDidReceiveListOfRooms:
```

check all rooms by chat room property isJoined. Determined request like a "getChatRoomsForCurrentUser" or some filters I don't found.

For 2) and 3) I think I should use Custom Objects, at this time I don't found any simple way how to do this.